# Wifi drivers failing at boot

Tags: boot, drivers, wireless

I have a Wlp2s0 Wifi driver, and it turns on and off at will. I'll turn on my laptop and my wifi will work perfect and the other 85% of the time it won't work. I am for sure the problem is that my drivers won't start on boot.

I have a asus x541n.
I am duel booting with windows 10
and have Ubuntu 19.04.

If you need any more info just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A WiFi connection is a common issue that can be either a software or a hardware issue. In Ubuntu, the NetworkManager makes the connection to wifi without you having to perform any manual task. At times however unexpected things might occur and you will have to configure or adjust the connection settings by yourself.

You first need to make sure that the problem is not related to the router or the modem. Try first to reboot these devices before proceeding to the troubleshooting steps. You might also want to verify your computer WiFi switch in case you have a laptop for instance.If you have a mobile phone or another PC, make sure the wifi connection is up and running and that the signal is strong enough.

Remember when you boot your computer to configure the automatic connection to a wireless network or a wired one in the NetworkManager.
the answer to this question can be very long - you can check this [guide](https://net2.com/how-to-fix-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu/) for instance. It might help you out...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but most the time I don't have a WiFi connection. Most the time it says that I don't have a adapter, but some times it will work with out a problem.